# Operand should contain 1 column(s) while executing select command

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0

Using Joomla whiole I am executing below query

```
select p.id, (select id,building_id
 from qu21k_ets_building_widgets 
where building_id = 47) as order_id 
from qu21k_ets_buildings p 
where p.id = 47
```

I am getting below error when I am executing above query.

> 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Results should be below as an array:

```
{

  "order_id":101,

  "building_id":1,

  "order_info":"apple related",

  "order_date":"2012-10-14 11:46:12",

  "_SQL_COL_1":

  [

    {
      "id":1001,
      "building_id":101,
      "name":"9.99"
    },
    {
      "item_id":1002,
      "building_id":101,
      "name":"19.99"
    }
  ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `building_id` from the subquery, select in subquery should contain ONE column.

Ig this should work:

```
select p.id, (select id
 from qu21k_ets_building_widgets 
where building_id = 47) as order_id 
from qu21k_ets_buildings p 
where p.id = 47
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a dependent subquery which is not an optimal solution instead use a join

```
SELECT p.id, 
w.id AS widgetid ,
w.building_id,
CONCAT(w.id,w.building_id) AS order_id 
FROM qu21k_ets_buildings p 
JOIN qu21k_ets_building_widgets w
ON(p.id = w.building_id)
WHERE p.id = 47 AND w.building_id = 47
```

Get your data and build array from it